# Show Custom Wizard Pages After Installation

Tags: inno-setup, wizard

Is there a way to show a custom wizard page or a custom page after the files have been dumped to the {app} directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, by specifying the correct page ID you want it to appear after when you create the page.
`wpInstalling`, `wpInfoAfter`, and `wpFinished` are all after the actual install.

Note that you shouldn't use the page numbers directly as they can change in different versions of Inno Setup

Comment: This was the identifier that I used! Thanks so much!
'ProgressPage := CreateCustomPage(wpInstalling + 1, 'Now Installing Your Software Packages', 'This could take a few minutes depending on your previous selections.');'

Comment: Why are you using wpInstalling+1? that's just the same as wpInfoAfter and you should never hard code pagee numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You could build a custom dialog using `CreateCustomForm` and call it using the `AfterInstall` hook of a File in the `[Files]` section.

Comment: Yeah, that was the method that I was going after. Unfortunately, Inno Setup goes straight to the finished page!

Comment: Sounds like your calling `Show` on the CustomForm instead call `ShowModal` to halt progress.

Comment: Also on other option.  Collect the information you need before the files are installed on a Custom Page.    Then in the AfterInstall perform the actions you need to do with the results.